# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' while building project

Tags: android, build

earlier was working fine but the time i updated the versions of libraries it went wrong

here is the app.gradle file, also tested with compile version 27 and 28 as well

```
  android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.test"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        }
    }
```

after changing dependendencies to androidX version , issue is there

```
 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
        implementation 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'

        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
```

in build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```